# Force close a scrapy spider

Tags: scrapy

So I have been beating my head against the wall for weeks on this problem. I have tried multiple solutions but I can't get something elegant to work. Ideally, I need to check for a file when a spider is opened and if the file is there stop execution. I can do this in the parse method but that's ugly and hard to maintain. I figure I can probably write some middleware to do this but for now I just want to implement it in each of my spiders. Here is what I have so far:

```
class MySpider(Spider):

    def __init__(self):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(MySpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        return spider

    def spider_opened(self):
        raise CloseSpider("Testing force close")
```

This doesn't work. I get the following exception:

```
2018-06-15 13:05:46 [scrapy.utils.signal] ERROR: Error caught on signal handler: <bound method ?.spider_opened of <MySpider 'myspider' at 0x10c450050>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 150, in maybeDeferred
result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.11-intel/egg/pydispatch/robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
  File "/Users/.../myspider.py", line 72, in spider_opened
    raise CloseSpider("Testing force close")
CloseSpider
```

In my IDE pylint says:

```
E1101:Instance of 'Spider' has no 'spider_opened' member
```

Can anyone point my to a solution? Is it because I am running Scrapy v1.3.0?

Answer (score 0):

It's should be like:

```
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher 
from scrapy import signals

class MySpider(Spider):

    def __init__(self):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(MySpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        return spider

    def spider_opened(self):
        raise CloseSpider("Testing force close")
```

Notice you can't declare `crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)`
inside the `classmethod`, because `spider_opened` should be called on spider instance.